# Extjs4 MVC, Add listener to view.Viewport in viewport controller

Tags: extjs4

I want to add 'afterrender' listener to view.Viewport to do something after render viewport.

anybody know how to do this?

My code is,

view.Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.viewport',
.
.
.
```

controller.Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function (application) {
        if (this.inited) {
            return;
        }
        this.inited = true;

        //console.log(this.getViewport());
        this.getViewport().addListener('load', function () {
            console.log('AFTER RENDER'); // it does not work....
        });
.
.
.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MVC Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture) guide shows you exactly how to do that.

From the doc:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
});
```

I guess if I match this to your code, it will be:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'viewport': {
                afterrender: this.onViewportRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onViewportRendered: function() {
        console.log('The viewport was rendered');
    }
});
```